# creation of MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

I am working to create a graph for POS data.  I

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(receipts.datenew - INTERVAL (5*60 + 30) MINUTE), INTERVAL (5*60 + 30)  MINUTE), '%Y-%m-%d') AS interval_start, 
CONVERT(EXTRACTVALUE(PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTES, '/properties//entry[@key=\"maincat\"]') USING UTF8) AS MAINCAT, 
ROUND(SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE * TICKETLINES.UNITS), -3) AS DAYSALES
FROM TICKETLINES, TICKETS, RECEIPTS, PRODUCTS 
WHERE TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID 
AND TICKETLINES.TICKET = TICKETS.ID 
AND TICKETS.ID = RECEIPTS.ID 
AND TICKETLINES.PRODUCT IS NOT NULL 
AND (receipts.datenew >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND receipts.person > 0) 
GROUP BY DATE(receipts.datenew - INTERVAL (5*60 + 30) MINUTE), MAINCAT
ORDER BY interval_start, MAINCAT
```

And I get the following data:

```
interval_start  MAINCAT DAYSALES
2016-12-31  Drink   45108000
2016-12-31  Food    49791000
2016-12-31  Other   109000
2017-01-01  Drink   14226000
2017-01-01  Food    27425000
2017-01-01  Other   36000
2017-01-02  Drink   20400000
2017-01-02  Food    25648000
2017-01-02  Other   109000
```

But I need this format:

```
interval_start  Drink       Food
2016-12-31  45108000    36000
2016-12-31  49791000    20400000
2016-12-31  109000        25648000
2017-01-01  27425000   109000
2017-01-01  14226000   49791000
```

I believe a subquery is the answer, but I am not able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Allan

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at the expected output.  I think you should include an explanation of that.

Comment: i think he want pivot the result

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I should have been more clear.  i am trying to create a chart and the vendor stated to produce the line graph, the data needs to have these columns.  The TICKETLINES table holds the prices of the sales items, and the sales date is in RECEIPTS.  My goal is to get sales data per day per type of item sold.  

I might be going about this completely wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the data in the correct format with the following query - thank you for pointing me in the right direction:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(receipts.datenew - INTERVAL (5*60 + 30) MINUTE), INTERVAL (5*60 + 30)  MINUTE), '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATEofSALES, 
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(EXTRACTVALUE(PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTES, '/properties//entry[@key=\"maincat\"]') USING UTF8) = 'Drink' THEN ticketlines.price ELSE 0 END) DRINKSALES,   
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(EXTRACTVALUE(PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTES, '/properties//entry[@key=\"maincat\"]') USING UTF8) = 'Food' THEN ticketlines.price ELSE 0 END) FOODSALES,
SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(EXTRACTVALUE(PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTES, '/properties//entry[@key=\"maincat\"]') USING UTF8) = 'Other' THEN ticketlines.price ELSE 0 END) OTHERSALES
FROM TICKETLINES, TICKETS, RECEIPTS, PRODUCTS 
WHERE TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID 
AND TICKETLINES.TICKET = TICKETS.ID 
AND TICKETS.ID = RECEIPTS.ID 
AND TICKETLINES.PRODUCT IS NOT NULL 
AND (receipts.datenew >= {ts '2017-02-01 06:00:00.000'} AND receipts.datenew < {ts '2017-03-31 14:28:00.000'} AND receipts.person > 0) 
GROUP BY DATE(receipts.datenew - INTERVAL (5*60 + 30) MINUTE) ORDER BY DATEofSALES
```